# Linear equation, parameter solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to solve a set of linear equations. But I am unsure of what method would be best suited. Yes this is a school related problem, where I have been asked to find the solution set.

$L_{1}: x_{1} + x_{2} + 2x_{3} + 3x_{4}$ = 13

$L_{2}: x_{1} - x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}$ = 8

$L_{3}: 3x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} - x_{4}$ = 1

I'm having a hard time isolating single variables of x, so I can determine values. Any hints?

Comment: Do you want subscripts on the variables?

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of methods you can use to solve problems like these. One way to do it is to throw your system of linear equations into an augmented matrix. What you want to do next is get your matrix into reduced row echelon form. Once you do that you'll have values for $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}$. Provided of course, that your system is consistent. When you get your values for $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}$ you can plug them back into your equation and make sure they're legit.